# How to build OpenSSL 1.1.1 for 64 bit Android using NDK 17

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

Failing to build OpenSSL for 64bit Android. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Downloaded the `setenv_android.sh` from https://wiki.openssl.org/images/7/70/Setenv-android.sh
2. Downloaded OpenSSL 1.1.1 from https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
3. Unpacked the tar file
4. Modified the setenv_android script so that running it produced this output:

   ```
   ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: /Users/spartygw/android-ndk-r17
   ANDROID_ARCH: arch-arm64
   ANDROID_EABI: aarch64-linux-android-4.9
   ANDROID_API: android-22
   ANDROID_SYSROOT: /Users/spartygw/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-22/arch-arm64
   ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN: /Users/spartygw/android-ndk-r17/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
   FIPS_SIG: 
   CROSS_COMPILE: aarch64-linux-android-
   ANDROID_DEV: /Users/spartygw/android-ndk-r17/platforms/android-22/arch-arm64/usr
   ```
5. Configured the openssl with: `./Configure no-rc5 no-idea no-md2  no-cast linux-aarch64`
6. Ran `make depend; make`

Output:

```
In file included from crypto/aes/aesv8-armx.S:1:
crypto/arm_arch.h:55:6: error: "unsupported ARM architecture"
#    error "unsupported ARM architecture"
     ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [crypto/aes/aesv8-armx.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This writeup makes it sound like I ran into this problem and stopped. I assure you I've spent a complete workday trying various things and googling to no avail. I don't want to litter the question with junk that I tried (passing in different ARM_ARCH values, trying other versions of openSSL, trying different NDKs).

Comment: This build script does not support arm64. Try https://github.com/noloader/Android-PRNG/blob/master/setenv-android.sh

Comment: @AlexCohn thank you so much. Using your script I was able to build correctly. If you'd like to submit as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scripts and examples on OpenSSL Wiki are badly outdated. The specific build script does not support arm64.

Luckily, GitHub comes to rescue: try https://github.com/noloader/Android-PRNG/blob/master/setenv-android.sh.

Comment: When i execute this script i am getting following error:
ERROR: AOSP_STL_LIB is not valid. Please edit this script.
And my Path looks like following:
AOSP_STL_LIB: /Users/dad/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi/libstlport_shared.so Do you know what i have to change to make it work?

Comment: @Dariusch, with the current NDK release you can only use `llvm-static` or `llvm-shared`, other STL variants have been dropped from NDK. Note that `mips` and `armeabi` have been dropped, too.

Comment: The link you provided is outdated, is there copy of that?

Comment: @support_ms I hope you don't really want to build OpenSSL with an 4-years-old NDK 17. Please see a [more up-to-date answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56876638/192373). 

You can also try [ndk-pkg](http://blog.fpliu.com/project/ndk-pkg/package?name=openssl).