# Linker fails to find library - with correct searchpath

Tags: makefile, linker, linker-errors

I have encountered a mysterious problem.
While having to compile some libraries for use on an Android Device, I met some linking problems between my code and OpenSSL.

I first compiled OpenSSL to Android, using a stand-alone toolchain, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656695/how-to-cross-compile-openssl-for-64-bit-android-on-osx-darwin-using-ndk-19). Then I had to link this with another library, which I configured to use the same toolchain.

```
./configure --host=aarch64-linux-android CPPFLAGS="-I/tmp/openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1n/include -DDEBUG" LDFLAGS=-L/tmp/openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1n
```

This configures fine, and then I run `make`.

Now the interesting thing pops up - the linker fails to find my library, as shown in the following error message.

```
libtool: link: aarch64-linux-android-gcc -DDEBUG -g -O2 -o .libs/credentialmanager credentialmanager-credentialmanager.o  -L/tmp/openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1n ./.libs/libcredentialutils.so ./.libs/libcredentialstack.so -L/usr/local/lib
/tmp/ndk-benlar/aarch64-linux-android/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.1, needed by ./.libs/libcredentialutils.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

I notice that it had two "-L" flags, however looking at the manpage, it should only *add* it to the search path, not replace it.

```
-L <dir>                Add directory to library search path
```

Looking in my temporary directory, I do see the library is located there.

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      16 Apr 28 11:58 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1

-rwxrwxr-x  1 user user 2754192 Apr 28 11:58 libcrypto.so.1.1
```

Why is the linker complaining about not finding the library, when it's obviously looking in the right folder, the files are the right name and the toolchain is the same.

Comment: You haven't actually shown us any error messages so there's no way to help.

Comment: @MadScientist woups - forgot the second line. The rest of the error is just undefined references.

Comment: Did you try to place `-L/tmp/openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1n` as last element in the command line? At least for static libs I think it is necessary that requested symbols need to be satisfied with objects supplied after, not before the request.

Comment: That won't help.  `-L` doesn't included any libraries, it only sets the path to be searched.  It's the `-l` (lowercase ell) that actually includes libraries and where the order matters.

Answer (score 2):

The error message gives you a hint as to the problem.  The `-L` option tells the linker where to find libraries to link, but that's not the issue here.  You are not linking `libcrypto` (there is no `-lcrypto` on your link line).  You are linking `credentialutils`, and *that* library is already linked to `crypto`.

It's that library that can't find its required libraries.

You need to either set the rpath on the `credentialutils` library so it knows where to look, or copy the crypto library into a place where it will be found, or set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to its location, or invoke the linker with `-rpath` pointing to the right location to look.

Comment: When looking at the output, I see the following:

/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link aarch64-linux-android-gcc -fPIC  -DTPM_TPM20 -DTPM_TPM12  -DTPM_POSIX -g -O2 -version-info 7:0:6 -L/tmp/openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1n -o libcredentialutils.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libcredentialutils_la-cryptoutils.lo libcredentialutils_la-ekutils.lo libcredentialutils_la-imalib.lo libcredentialutils_la-eventlib.lo libicredentialutils_la-efilib.lo libcredentialmanager.la -lcrypto  

This doesn't fail. I see rpath pointing different, even though -L is set - but copying to the path doesn't work...

Comment: You have to clearly separate in your mind the _link-time search path_ from the _run-time search path_.  When creating a .so or an executable, you link it and the libraries you list on the link line are searched in the _link-time_ search path, which is specified with `-L`.  However, none of those paths are automatically added to the _run-time_ search path.  The run-time search path is consulted when that library or binary you created is loaded.

Comment: Based on the info above, it should work if you copy the `libcrypto.so.1.1.1` file into `/usr/local/lib`, which is the run-time link path for `credentialutils`, and so that's where libraries that are needed to load `credentialutils` will be searched for.  Of course it's possible that something else changed it.  You should run `ldd libcredentialutils.so` and see that `libcrypto` is found.  More info here: https://codeyarns.com/tech/2017-11-01-how-shared-library-locations-are-found-at-runtime.html

Comment: I agree that it should work. 
file /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped.

It's the correct type, and it exists, but still the same result.